# Generate list of classes from SCSS list

Tags: sass

**QUESTION:** Is it possible to use a SCSS list to generate a number of classes without repeating the attributes?

The point is to keep the file easy maintainable by have ONE list ($svgs) of names which then can be used for classes or variables (see example below, $svg). This list is much larger in reality.

Note that I can't use `.box i[class*=".icon-"]` or similar selectors, as there are other elements that would be affected.

Here's the current SCSS, which works, but creates bloated CSS. .

```
$svgs: cancel, danger, exit;

@each $svg in $svgs {
  .box i.icon- {
    &#{$svg} {
      background-image: url($svg + '.svg');

      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
    }
  }
}
```

Result CSS is:

```
.box i.icon-cancel {
  background-image: url("cancel.svg");
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.box i.icon-danger {
  background-image: url("danger.svg");
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.box i.icon-exit {
  background-image: url("exit.svg");
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Desired CSS:

```
.box i.icon-cancel, .box i.icon-danger, .box i.icon-exit {  
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.box i.icon-cancel {
  background-image: url("cancel.svg");
}

.box i.icon-danger {
  background-image: url("danger.svg");
}

.box i.icon-exit {
  background-image: url("exit.svg");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this result you can use [@extend](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) with a [placeholder selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors):

```
$svgs: cancel, danger, exit;

%svg-styles {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

@each $svg in $svgs {
  .box i.icon- {
    &#{$svg} {
      @extend %svg-styles;
      background-image: url($svg + '.svg');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a great combination! Thank you.